# 18.04 LTS: Dual Boot issue on Acer Swift 3 315-41

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I installed the latest ubuntu with the standard dual boot procedure alongside the pre-installed Windows.

The resulting partitions are:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1FD93AC5-481F-46E4-8743-4C1B0493E4D3

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    239616 217887637 217648022 103.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498020352 500117503   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 217888768 498020351 280131584 133.6G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I configured the boot sequence in the UEFI with ubuntu (grub) first.

The resulting EFI configuration is:

```
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

On boot, grub normally shows up with the default option "ubuntu" selected. Another option is "Windows Boot Manager".

ubuntu starts normally, and if I shutdown the system and restart later, everything continues to work.
But if I try to reboot from ubuntu, a "no boot device" screen comes up and I have to hard shut down with the power button. On the next start, Windows will boot directly (without passing through grub). If I then go into the UEFI Bios, the boot order is inverted with Windows first. I have to re-invert it in order to start ubuntu again, which is quite annoying.

Fastboot has been disabled in Windows. When I boot Windows from grub and then reboot from Windows, the machine turns now normally to grub. So the only thing not working is the reboot from ubuntu.

What puzzles me is, that efibootmgr does not show a partition Boot0000 as instead in all examples I have seen around. Maybe it has nothing to do with my problem, but it's the only difference, I see.

I can only assume, that on ubuntu reboot, the system tries to boot directly from /dev/nvme0n1p5 (the linux filesystem), which is not marked as bootable at all. But I cannot find any setting, that influences this behaviour.

Any other ideas? Thanx a lot in advance.

Further Details:

```
root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI# ls -la
insgesamt 7
drwx------ 7 root root 1024 Jun  9 13:02 .
drwx------ 4 root root 1024 Jan  1  1970 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 1024 Jun 13 19:25 Boot
drwx------ 2 root root 1024 Jun  9 13:02 Insyde
drwx------ 4 root root 1024 Mär 28 15:48 Microsoft
drwx------ 4 root root 1024 Jun 10 15:50 OEM
drwx------ 3 root root 1024 Jun  6 23:33 ubuntu
root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI# ls Boot/
bootx64.efi  fbx64.efi
root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI# ls Insyde
root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI# ls Microsoft
Boot  Recovery
root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI# ls OEM
Boot  Recovery
root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI# ls ubuntu
BOOTX64.CSV  fw  fwupx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI#
```

[My grub.cfg](https://pastebin.com/LLTU5D3c)

Comment: Once you are in Ubuntu, can you try `sudo update-grub` and post the terminal output?

Comment: <pre>root@JensNewLap:/boot/efi/EFI/Boot# update-grub
GRUB-Konfigurationsdatei wird erstellt …
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-22-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-22-generic
Windows Boot Manager auf /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi gefunden
Hinzufügen des Boot-Menü Eintrages für die EFI Firmware Konfiguration
erledigt
</pre>

Comment: "When you boot ubuntu via grub, grub comes up" as you said this grub is showing windows 10 or not?

Comment: OK, I'll try to be a bit more precise.

Comment: 1. Step: Set ubuntu as first boot entry in the UEFI BIOS

Comment: 2. Step: Grub shows up, with default choice for ubuntu. Other choice is "Windows Boot Loader"

Comment: 3.a Step: boot and then shutdown ubuntu. Restart the machine - return to Step 2.

Comment: 3.b Step: boot and then reboot ubuntu. Windows will boot without any choice. Need to go back to 1.

Comment: 3.c Step: boot Windows and than shutdown Windows. Restart the machine - return to step 2.

Comment: 3.d Step: boot Windows and than reboot from there. Windows will boot without any choice. Need to go back to step 1.

Comment: So it might not be directly ubuntu related - either a Windows and a ubuntu reboot mess up the boot order in the UEFI.

Comment: OK.. I understood. In your BIOS if there is fast boot.. Disable it. When you login to windows disable fast boot.

Comment: As long as you see grub and the options of both Ubuntu and windows with in the grub... Evert thing is fine.. Only thing is fast boot and the BIOS settings

Comment: Even after disabling the fast boot and if the problem still exists... If you can share the BIOS options screens, share it in a link here.. As per my understanding you don't have any issue with dual booting.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit confusing: I missed the most important part in the steps above - the "no boot device" screen. So I re-wrote the description. I still think, there must be a flaw in the ubuntu config, that does not enable the reboot at all.

Comment: Disabling fastboot repaired at least the reboot from Windows. But reboot from ubuntu is still broken.

Comment: some screen shots will let us understand the concept. Boot Options screen from BIOS/UEFI. The mode of your Windows installed via UEFI/BOOT mode? Ubuntu Installed in which mode? what is your disk partitioning style?

Comment: if you go to BIOS Options and search, you may find something like "Boot Sequence After Restart" select the choice same as you mentioned in your question, "I configured the boot sequence in the UEFI with ubuntu (grub) first."

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a workaround. I need to specify the kernel boot parameter "reboot=pci". To do so, you can edit /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=pci"
```

and update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

That's it. Rebooting seems to last quite long, but at least it works.

It might be worth filing a bug to the linux kernel for a quirk in order to add an entry to the [reboot_dmi_table](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c#L158)?

Comment: I filed a bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200241